# How to get dynamic input fields value to csv then attache to email

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I have created this form http://norcaltoc.com/toc-form.html where user can add or remove fields. Those fields name is like name0,name1,name2. Now how can i write those dynamic values to a csv file then attache the csv file to email. Can anyone please help by write the process.php code? I need the csv file as attached. Thanks in advance.

[Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vT4H.png)

Comment: Please anyone can help me. I am totally getting stuck. How can i do that? Please help

Comment: OK nobody help me as it was urgent. Thanks for everyone. I have solved this problem. If anyone need to fix this kind of problem just knock me on skype: smtareq786